# Can someone translate sentance from english to chinese?

Tags: translation

If there was a price for my love, you could never afford it.

Comment: Closing as offtopic. Translations without prior effort are not allowed here.

Comment: OK, Google, say "if there was a price for my love, you could never afford it" in Chinese.

Comment: @Mia You should consider removing this question as it does not help the site in any way and is the equivalent of clutter. It is a valid question but just doesn't rise to the level expected on this site. I encourage you to either delete or edit the question so that it becomes more valuable. Some ways you could do that are by adding context, exploring the grammar associated with the question (or the answer), or reviewing alternatives. These are just examples, please review other questions asked here to get a sense of how you can expand the question so that it will benefit the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, 如果我的爱有个价钱，那么你永远无法付的起.

In other words, 我的爱是无价的。（My love is priceless）

Answer (score 2):

If there was a price for my love, you could never afford it.

1. 若 吾愛 待沽，汝 永難 承擔。
2. 如果 我的愛 要定個 價錢，你 絕不可能 買得起。